# Status on the Tagged PDF project

Tags: latex3, tagged-pdf

Does aynone know what the status of the Tagged PDF project is? How far has the LaTeX3 Team progressed on the timeline from section 3 of "[LaTeX Tagged PDF -- Feasibility Evaluation](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-tagged-pdf-feasibility.pdf)"?

Also, are there any new articles regarding the project?

Comment: https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/pdf/ has some 2021 updates plus of course the package doc for tagpdf and related packages

Comment: Well naturally someone knows ;-). The next tugboat will contain an article from Frank and me about the general status, and also an article about the special task 2.3.4 Metadata management (mostly xmp metadata).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting. Will you provide a link when the article becomes available?

Comment: become a TUG member ;-) Then you can read it soon. But beside this we put such articles in due course on the side mentioned by David.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point -- I should actually do that. :-)

Comment: Any response to this?  I'm contemplating TUG so I can look at it - although presumably the first issue of 2023 will be out soon so that the previous issue will become publicly available ... ??

Comment: The TUGboat article appears to be [here](https://tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb43-3/tb135mitt-tagged.pdf) ; I'm not currently a member of TUG, but thinking about joining so I can see/summarize this paper.  Would someone please post **some** answer so the bounty doesn't get wasted?

Comment: Last chance for someone to post **some** kind of answer and get the bounty ...

Comment: Oh well ........

Comment: @BenBolker You should have pinged somebody - probably Ulrike. :)